# Is it possible to make a "jiggle bone" respond to a shape key? Is there a better way to create "bounce" with shape keys?

Tags: animation, rigging, workflow

I am testing animation techniques on a simple character.  I have an armature with "jiggle bones" set up, and the "jiggle bones" are effective in creating a wobble in the plump parts of my character, but only when I am animating using the armature.  Is it possible to allow shape keys to affect the jiggle bones?  Or is there a way to get a similar jiggle effect with softbody/cloth physics?  What is the best way to get a jigglebone-type effect while animating with shape keys?

When I have tried to use softbody physics, the result is always, so far, a "rippling sheet" effect, and what I want is a realistic "belly-laugh" jiggle.

Rippling sheet effect when animating the character with shape keys and softbody physics:

[image]

I also want the character to be able to fly through the air without becoming an empty pillowcase, but rather maintain a slight bounce.  Even a steady, slight ripple would be ok.  Here is the pillowcase effect that i cannot seem to escape:

[image]

[image]

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Did you tried Jiggle Armature Addon?
Preview https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwkNO93XBH4
Download https://github.com/cheece/JiggleArmature